# how to add serch function using ajax in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, ajax, search

i want to add search function in which firstly there will be three select box but two of will be disabled when user select some value from or or say example year from drop down then second field is enabled which has car company name relevant to that year and after selecting car company relevant model no opens and then after selecting relevant car model no its parts list will be open and following will be search. so can anyone tell me how to start this. which files i have to add or change for this.

Comment: it would take lots of programming modification and customization. I would recommend you use some extension instead.

Comment: so can you suggest me the name of few good extension to implement this functionality as i have searched but couldn't find the right one

Comment: here is a link of extension by amasty: http://amasty.com/product-parts-finder.html I haven't used it till now but i'll be using it for my next project.